# Can I have checkboxes and radio buttons on the same "CreateInputOptionPage" page in Inno Setup?

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

Is it possible to have both the radio buttons and checkboxes on the same page using `CreateInputOptionPage`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `AExclusive` parameter of `TInputOptionWizardPage.AddEx` method to choose between a radio button or a checkbox:

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  Page: TInputOptionWizardPage;
begin
  Page := CreateInputOptionPage(wpWelcome, '', '', '', False, False);

  Page.AddEx('Radio button 1', 0, True);
  Page.AddEx('Radio button 2', 0, True);
  Page.AddEx('Check box 1', 0, False);
  Page.AddEx('Check box 2', 0, False);
end;
```

[image]